# Django forms - looping through form choice fields, how to assign the ID?

Tags: django, forms

I am looping through some form choice fields in my template, but when I post, the form is not valid as it is missing required field "subnets" however I have manually created the subnet checkboxes. The reason I believe it is failing is because the manually created objects do not have an id, is this right? and how do I assign the id?

template:

```
{% for value, text in form.subnets.field.choices %}
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="subnets" value="{{ value }}" />{{ text }}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
```

error:

```
subnets
This field is required.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkboxes should have `name` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="subnets" name="subnets" value="{{ value }}" />{{ text }}
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it for me!]